# Extract everything between quotes

Tags: shell, sed, grep, regular-expression

I am trying to use grep or sed to extract a url from a string which looks like `javascript:open_window("http://www.example.com/somescript.ext?withquerystring=true");`

The javascript link is generated -- by an external application I have no control over -- each time, so I have to extract the URL to use it. I have tried and failed to use a whole host of combinations of grep and sed, which haven't worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/.*\("(.*)"\).*/\1/'
```

Example:

```
echo 'javascript:open_window("http://www.example.com/somescript.ext?withquerystring=true")' | sed -E 's/.*\("(.*)"\).*/\1/'
http://www.example.com/somescript.ext?withquerystring=true
```

Comment: You are looking for parenthesis? Why? Just remove those: `sed -E 's/.*"(.*)".*/\1/'` Question is: "Extract everything between quotes" not "Extract everything between quotes with parenthesis". Make your answer more generalized - it will still work for OP.

Answer (score 6):

Simply with GNU **`grep`**:

```
s='javascript:open_window("http://www.example.com/somescript.ext?withquerystring=true");'
grep -Eo 'http:[^"]+' <<<"$s"
http://www.example.com/somescript.ext?withquerystring=true
```

Comment: Doesn't make much sense to me to use `grep -P` if `grep -E` does the same.

Comment: @HaukeLaging, true, updated. (Unintentionally missed)

Answer (score 1):

You could `cut` the output, specifying ' " ' (double quotes) as the delimiter.

```
$ invar='javascript:open_window("http://www.example.com/somescript.ext?withquerystring=true");'
$ echo $invar | cut -d '"' -f2
http://www.example.com/somescript.ext?withquerystring=true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = "\42"} {print $2}' <<'eof'
javascript:open_window("http://www.example.com/somescript.ext?withquerystring=true");
eof
```

Answer (score 0):

```
e='javascript:open_window("http://www.example.com/somescript.ext?withquerystring=true");'
```

The sed command will help:

```
sed -E 's/.*(http.*)\);/\1/' <<< "$e"
echo 'javascript:open_window("http://www.example.com/somescript.ext?withquerystring=true");' | sed -E 's/.*"(http.*)"\);/\1/'
```

Result:

```
http://www.example.com/somescript.ext?withquerystring=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved same by using below sed command

command

```
echo 'javascript:open_window("http://www.example.com/somescript.ext?withquerystring=true");'|  sed "s/.*(//g" l.txt  | sed 's/"//g' | sed "s/).*//g"
```

output

```
http://www.example.com/somescript.ext?withquerystring=true
```

Comment: (1) Why bother?  There are two `sed` answers ahead of yours, and they are both simpler than yours. (2) If you read the documentation, or any of the thousands of `sed` questions on this site, you’ll see that you hardly ever need to pipe `sed` into `sed`.  A three-``sed`` pipeline is definitely unnecessary.